# Generic code failed with Spring data and Querydsl

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, querydsl

i use `querydsl` that's why i don't need method like `findByName()` and all my repository interface are empty.

So i try to make genric code to avoid repetitive interface with empty methods because i have many classes in my entities mapped by hibernate.

```
public interface GenericResposotory<T> 
              extends JpaRepository<T, Integer>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> {

}
```

When I run my server I get this error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'genericResposotory': 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class java.lang.Object
```

also there is not a way to make a generic repository like i try to do ?

Comment: which spring version are you on?

Comment: i use 4.0.5.RELEASE for spring and 1.6.0.RELEASE for spring-data-jpa

Answer (score 2):

Spring data tries to create beans for all interfaces you create that extend JpaRepository. If you want to have a kind of base repository that will not be used mark your interface with [@NoRepositoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/NoRepositoryBean.html)

Comment: I mark it but i get `Could not autowire field: private repository.GenericRespository` when i try `@Autowired
 private GenericRespository<Region> region_repository;`

Comment: Ok, so I misunderstood the question. I thought that this interface is a base for other things and you extend it with other interfaces. In that case I dont think it's possible to achieve what you want. You simply have to extend the genericinterface with some other and set T to some class.

Answer (score 0):

`Repository` is a marker interface for spring, that helps to find your own extended repositories and create repository by extracting the type of the entity. We can see in `RepositoryFactorySupport`:

> Factory bean to create instances of a given repository interface.
>   Creates a proxy implementing the configured  * repository interface
>   and apply an advice handing the control to the
>   QueryExecuterMethodInterceptor . Query  * detection strategy can be
>   configured by setting  QueryLookupStrategy.Key.

That's why, i think, you can't create generic repository directly.

But you can try to use `RepositoryFactorySupport` (implemented `JpaRepositoryFactory`) to generate repositories and put it into context manually.

Also, you can reduce the number of files in project and namespace pollution  by defining repositories as inner interfaces: just add an attribute as shown below:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.pack" consider-nested-repositories="true"/>
```